# Coprime sum of prime factors

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was experimentally able to verify the following:

> **Conjecture.** Let $n=2ap$ be an integer with $a\geq 2$ and $p$ being the smallest odd prime dividing $n$. Then there is $k\geq 1$ for which
> the following hold:
>
> - $p+2k<\frac n2$.
> - $p+2k$ is coprime to $n$.

My goal is actually to find a sum of prime factors of $n$ which is smaller than $\frac n2$, and which is coprime to $n$. The proposed conjecture would solve this problem.

How can this conjecture be tackled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $p+2k$ equal to $ap-1$ if $a$ is even, and to $ap-2$ if $a$ is odd.

Answer (score 2):

The desired conclusion can be stated more simply as "some integer between $p$ and $\frac n2$ is coprime to $n$". I believe the following argument proves this once a couple of details are filled in:

- If $p>3$:

  - if $a\ge3$, then some power of $3$ is between $p$ and $\frac n2$ and is coprime to $n$;
  - if $a=2$, then $p+2$ is between $p$ and $\frac n2$ and is coprime to $n$.
- If $p=3$, then the smallest prime not dividing $n$ is between $p$ and $\frac n2$ and is coprime to $n$.